# How might I move an existing entity into a different c# namespace and maintain migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, namespaces, migration, refactoring, entity-framework-core

Say I have an existing code-first entity (with multiple established migrations) that looks like this:

```
namespace OldNamespace
{
    [Table("Widget", Schema = "summat")]
    public class Widget
    {
    }
}
```

And I want to move it to a `NewNamespace` in a C# sense (but not in a database table sense):

```
namespace NewNamespace
{
    [Table("Widget", Schema = "summat")]
    public class Widget
    {
    }
}
```

The model snapshot that is generated includes the full c# namespace of the entity, so it seems problematic that EF will know what an old/existing namespace will be after a migration?

```
    protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
          //...
            modelBuilder.Entity("OldNamespace.Widget", b =>
            {
            }
    }
```

Has anyone done this sort of thing? How can I do the refactor without having to "squash" all migrations? Is there a way to set up metadata so that EF can follow the namespace refactor?

EF Core version: 1.0.1

Update: A new ef core migration looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not been able to reproduce it.

**Added Widget entity to Models folder:**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    [Table("Widget", Schema = "summat")]
    public class Widget
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Created a migration.** `(dotnet ef migrations add AddWidget)` Got this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.EnsureSchema(
                name: "summat");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Widget",
                schema: "summat",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Widget", x => x.Id);
                });
        }
```

**Moved the entity to Domain.Entities folder.**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Domain.Entities
{
    [Table("Widget", Schema = "summat")]
    public class Widget
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Added another migration:** `dotnet ef migrations add MoveWidget`. Got this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
}
```

Comment: Did you change the namespaces of the pre-refactor migrations? or just let them be?

Comment: Also, were you able to run the migrations/update? Generation of the migration code is one thing, but successfully continuing the migration process is another (as is applying the migrations to existing data situations).

Comment: @automatonic, no I didn't. Just let them be. I was able to successfully run database update commands. If you want I can upload the solution to a github repo so you can play with it and maybe try to reproduce the issue. Just let me know.

Comment: I will soon be in a position to try this with the actual target entities. I had hit an issue before (thus the question) but that was in the RC1 version of ef core. Perhaps it will just work. Thank you for your time in investigating.

Comment: Indeed it just worked. I have a recollection of trying it in one of the EF7 release candidate versions. Either i had some other issue (find and replace broke my connection string, etc.) or there was a problem there. This is why I was trying to understand how to do it right. Thank you for your straightforward test/suggestion. I was able to rename my entities, add new columns to existing databases, and rebuild the database from scratch without issue.

Answer (score 4):

> The model snapshot that is generated includes the full c# namespace of the entity, so it seems problematic that EF will know what an old/existing namespace will be after a migration?

This is not problematic. At the end of the day, these are just opaque strings used at design-time. The fact that're the same as your old namespace names is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the official weigh-in. Not sure why i had it in my head that the C# namespace mattered, but after trying/testing what you assert rings true. Paranoia strikes deep and all that.